# IE9 setting background-image to "none" via inline style

Tags: css, internet-explorer, internet-explorer-9, background-image

The site I am currently working on is http://rattscallion.com/ I am focusing my efforts on getting the site to look proper in IE.

I was having trouble getting the frame on the pages (look at /murals.html for the page I'm working on first). IE9 said that the inline-style stated that the background-image was "none," so it crossed out the original background image. I figured it might be getting this from somewhere on the main stylesheet so what I did was make a new frame that only exists in IE and style it only in the IE stylesheet. Unfortunately this also doesn't work...it still says that an inline-style is setting the background-image to "none", but there is no such thing!

I double-checked and this is happening in IE9 standards mode. So why is this happening? Can anyone help figure out how to "force" it over what IE perceives as the inline style?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well there's your problem:

```
CSS was ignored due to mime type mismatch 
normalize.css
```

If you check the network calls the normalize.css is received as text/plain instead of text/css. You should install static content (under server roles) in your IIS as for some weird reason it's not installed by default. I'm betting one WHOLE dollar you're using IIS.

You could have just copy pasted the normalize.css into a server side css file so it's not accessed remotely.

I got it working by doing the following:

- remove `#framePos img{ display: none; }` from styles-ie.css
- remove unitpngfix.js - the png filter fix was for ie6 and serves no purpose on ie9 (it's actually one of the reasons the frame does not show)

Note: the frame.png pic is place in lots'o'places as background so you should consider a little clean up of the css files

Another Note: unitpngfix.js replaces the frame.png with the clear.gif and places transparency filters on every png element. So tinkering on css will not do anything until you remove the js.

Comment: The server is running `Apache` and the `normalize.css` comes from github. Best bet would be to download and upload to their server.

Comment: There goes my dollar. Although I find it hard to believe apache sends wrong mime types for static content. IIS does that with no static content server role. I'll hold on to it for now.

Comment: Thanks for the tip, that may help me get to the bottom of this. I'm not in control of the server, I'm doing this for a friend. But I'll see if getting rid off normalize helps or if I can try to pass it a different way.

Comment: I removed normalize.css and still getting the same problem. What do you think now?

Comment: Thanks for your help. I've gotten everything fixed and it turns out I was able to remove my conditional stylesheet. Great help!